# Extract row number of range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract the row number of a range and add `+1` to it in `VBA`. 
Therefore, I tried to go with this `VBA`:

```
Sub Extract_Row ()
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Split(Sheet1.Range("L28").Address, "$")(2) + 1
Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = Split(Sheet1.Range("L28:AE28").Address, "$")(2) + 1
End Sub
```

It works for the first option where I only select one cell `L28`. 
For the second option where I select a range `L28:AE28` I get `runtime error 13`.

What do I need to change in the second option to make it work as well?

Comment: So what exactly would you expect in your second example? An array or a single value? If you are just looking for a single value > `Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Sheet1.Range("L28:AE28").Row + 1`. This would simply get the row of the first cell in a range and add 1. No need to `Split()` anything here.

Comment: I am expecting a single value so your comment is the solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Sheet1.Range("L28:AE28").Address` return the string "$L$28:$AE$28". If you split, the second element of the array will be "28:" that cannot be converted to a number, hence the error 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, no need to `Split()`, use:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Sheet1.Range("L28:AE28").Row + 1
```

Where `.Row` would return the row index of the top left cell in a `Range` object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UBound()` to extract last item of array. Try below sub...

```
Sub Extract_Row()
 Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = Split(Sheet1.Range("L28:AE28").Address, "$")(UBound(Split(Sheet1.Range("L28:AE28").Address, "$"))) + 1
End Sub
```